# UIButton animation extension

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibutton

I'm attempting to reduce redundancy of repetitive code that's used throughout an app by creating a standard animation function.

My desired outcome is an animation for a button with an optional completion handler. Here's my code:

```
extension UIButton {  
  func animate(duration: TimeInterval, completion: ((Bool) -> Swift.Void)?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 6.0, options: [], animations: {
      self.transform = .identity
    }, completion: completion)
  }
}
```

On `MyViewController`, when I call the animation method like this, the segue happens, but the animation does not:

```
myButton.animate(duration: 0.25) { _ in
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySequeIdentifier", sender: sender)
}
```

I commented out the `self.performSegue` to ensure the segue was not hard-wired on the storyboard, and verified it is not.

I also tried declaring the animation function with this code:

```
func animate(duration: TimeInterval, completion: @escaping (Bool)->Void?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 6.0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
      self.transform = .identity
    }, completion: completion as? (Bool) -> Void)
}
```

Using that code, nothing happens. Not even a crash.

Thank you for reading. I welcome your suggestions re: where my mistake lies.

Comment: try giving some delay say 0.3 sec.

Comment: Same result. Segue happens, animation does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well its not animating because I think you forgot to give initial transform value to button before calling extension method.

```
  myButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)
myButton.animate(duration: 0.25) { _ in
  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySequeIdentifier", sender: sender)
}
```